# Proving a beautiful relation between number 11 and infinite sums?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

When we were studying recurring decimals for the first time (that was long ago), I noticed something remarkable whenever I divided a number by 11. 
For example $\frac{9}{11}= 0.818181...=0.\overline{81}=0.\overline{(9\times9)} $
We can write it as an infinite sum this way: 
$$\frac 9 {11}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(8 \times 10^{-(2n-1)} +10^{-2n} \right) $$ 
And then if we try another number between $0$ and $9$, let's choose $7$, we get the same thing: 
$\frac 7{11}= 0.636363...=0.\overline{63}=0.\overline{(9\times7)}$
I tried to generalize the previous result and here's what I've got:
$$ \frac x{11}= \frac {x-a}{11} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{a-u}{10} \times 10^{-(2n-1)} +u \times 10^{-2n} \right)$$
known that:
$ x \equiv a\pmod {11} $ and  $ 9a \equiv u \pmod {10}$ 
 I hope it's correct! -crossed fingers- 
So, my question is can you help me get a better generalization only using $x$ and $n$ ? And is there any way to prove this result ? If there's any please be as simple as you can and provide explanation. I guess it has something to do with $11$ being the first whole number after $10$ in base $10$.

Comment: This is a combination of a couple of well-known patterns, which to some of us might be "obvious", but it's put together so thoughtfully that I'm glad to see it already has at least one good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is that when $a=1,2,\dots,9$ then $u=10-a$.

It's easier to see it if you write $\frac{1}{11}=0.090909\dots$ and then the question is about multiples of $9$. So $9a=10(a-1)+(10-a)$. And $u\equiv 9a\equiv -a\equiv 10-a\pmod{10}$.

---

This actually generalizes to other bases.

$$\frac{1}{b+1} = \frac{b-1}{b^2}+\frac{b-1}{b^4}+\cdots$$

And for $a=1,\dots,b$ you get:

$$\frac{a}{b+1} = \frac{(a-1)b+(b-a)}{b^2}+\frac{(a-1)b+(b-a)}{b^4}+\cdots$$